# How to use Postman with OSWAP Zap Proxy?

Tags: rest, postman, zap

I'm trying to explore a REST API using ZAP and Postman but I get an error probably because I didn't set up something right.
Should I add the SA certificate from ZAP to Postman?

> Could not get any response
>   There was an error connecting to http://myurl.
>   Why this might have happened:
>   The server couldn't send a response:
>   Ensure that the backend is working properly
>   Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
>   Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
>   Proxy configured incorrectly
>   Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
>   Request timeout:
>   Change request timeout in Settings > General

Comment: Look like all the URLs are http, without SSL. Can you access the `http://myurl`? Can Zap access it?

Comment: Yes I can access the url. Actually I'm testing a POST request. ZAP returns a 406 for this URL.

Comment: This is weird, did the request get to your API? Is Zap running locally? How did you set the proxy?